# IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019-1.3 from jetbrain website. When I clicked on it, it showed jetbrain privcy policy including:
you may object to the processing of your personal data for the purposes b) to e) at any time.
Categories of data involved in data processing include:
names,
email address,
phone number,
username,
password,
cookies,
IP address,
SSH public key,
physical address,
information about subscription and payments, and
tax ID.
It is required to click confirm button to open / run intelliJ. if not I can not open the intelliJ.
My concern is that they may use my privacy information.
What do you suggest?

Comment: Did you ask this question to the IntelliJ IDEA creators?

Comment: What's your specific concern? We do use the information exactly as described in the privacy policy. We're not collecting any information that you do not explicitly enter in the product or on our Web sites (e.g. we will not know your phone number unless you specify it when buying a license or contacting support).

Answer (score 1):

There is an option inside IntelliJ to enable or disable data sharing:

[image: IntelliJ Data Sharing Dialog]

This option can be found in the settings:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-usage-statistics.html

I can't confirm what this changes, but it looks to at least reduce if not turn off the collection of private information.